# why scrapy doesn't it call the function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

why the doesn't work **else** in **parse_cat**? I need to go back a step if the **search_prod** variable is empty. So in general, is it possible to do? Where is my mistake?

```
def parse_sub_cat(self, response):
for i in response.xpath('//a[@data-track-action="CategoryOverviewNavigation"]'):
    goods_url = response.urljoin(i.xpath("./@href").get())
    product_parent = i.xpath("./text()").get()
    yield response.follow(
        url=goods_url,
        callback=self.parse_cat,
        cb_kwargs=dict(product_parent=product_parent)
    )

def parse_cat(self, response, **cb_kwargs):
search_prod = response.css('article.m-grid-tile').css('div.m-grid-tile--image')
if search_prod is not None:
    for i in search_prod:
        ulr_product = response.urljoin(i.css('a::attr("href")').get())
        cb_kwargs['model'] = i.css('a::attr("aria-label")').get()
        yield response.follow(
            url=ulr_product,
            callback=self.parse_product,
            cb_kwargs=cb_kwargs
        )
else:
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=response.url,
        callback=self.parse_sub_cat,
    )
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Have you checked if `prod_list` and `prod_list.css('a.product.photo.product-item-photo::attr("href")').getall()` are not empty?

Comment: you're not yielding the `scrapy.Request`, you have to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `yield` your `scrapy.Request`.
Try to

```py
 def parse_page(self, response, **cb_kwargs):
    show_all = response.css('a.button.btn-small::attr("href")').get()
    if show_all is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=show_all, callback=self.parse_page)

    prod_list = response.css('ol.products.list.items.product-items')
    for url in prod_list.css('a.product.photo.product-item-photo::attr("href")').getall():
        yield response.follow(
            url=response.urljoin(url),
            callback=self.parse_product,
            cb_kwargs=cb_kwargs
        )

    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@title="Next"]/@href').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: yes!!! thank you!!! my inattention (((

Comment: you're welcome :D

Comment: please look at the updated code, why else doesn't work for me in the parse_cat function?